# getting unreadable symbols using ruby-smpp

Tags: ruby, smpp, ruby-smpp

I'm using ruby-smpp to send ussd requests, for now everything working fine with ISO-8859-1 symbols, except Cyrllic.

```
optionals = {0x0501 => Smpp::OptionalParameter.new(0x0501, '\u0011')}
send_mt("055012", "066012", "Привет", {optional_parameters: optionals, data_coding: 8})
```

**submit_sm.rb**

```
@short_message = short_message.encode("UTF-16BE").force_encoding("BINARY")
```

but anyway getting unreadable symbols, can it be the carrier issue?

p.s also tries this commit: https://github.com/kubum/ruby-smpp/commit/72eb124c45df962a5412f7a821ccb02cccdabe60, but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the USSDC with which i was working with uses `data_coding: 72`, someway. Resolved.